# onActivityResult method not working.

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a small application that launches a "login" activity as a sub activity from my main application activity. The login activity collects username and password using EditText fields and then sends the credentials to main activity for validation after clicking a submit button. For some reason though, my onActivityResult() is not working. I even tried including a TextView that I would manipulate at different points of the method to deduce where it is going wrong, but it appears that the method itself isn't executing for some reason. Any help would be much appreciated.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String userName = "9590778";
private final String userPass = "1234567";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void activity_about(View view){
    Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
    startActivity(aboutIntent);
}

public void activity_login(View view){
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(loginIntent, LoginActivity.LOGIN_REQUEST);
}

public void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent resultIntent){
    String passedUser;
    String passedPass;

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    TextView lblTest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTest);
    lblTest.setText("ATLEAST THIS IS WORKING!"); //THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO MANIPULATE THE TEXTVIEW TO SEE IF METHOD IS EXECUTING!

    if(requestCode == LoginActivity.LOGIN_REQUEST){

        passedUser = intent.getStringExtra("PASSED_USER");
        passedPass = intent.getStringExtra("PASSED_PASS");

        if(passedUser.equals(userName)){
            if(passedPass.equals(userPass)){
                lblTest.setText("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!");
            }
        }
        else{
            lblTest.setText("ACCESS DENIED!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Also, this is my LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

public static final int LOGIN_REQUEST = 9999;
public static final int LOGIN_RESPONSE = 1234;

private String passedUser;
private String passedPass;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
    return true;
}

public void submitCred(View view){

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    EditText lblUser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    EditText lblPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

    passedUser = lblUser.getText().toString();
    passedPass = lblPass.getText().toString();


    intent.putExtra("PASSED_USER", passedUser);
    intent.putExtra("PASSED_PASS", passedPass);
    setResult(LOGIN_RESPONSE, intent);

    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo, the function you want is `onActivityResult`, (notice the lowercase `o`).

It's a good habit to use the @Override statement before any method you want to override. If you put @Override before `OnActivityResult` in your case it would complain at you that `OnActivityResult` is not a superclass method.

It's a good check to make sure you have the right name and right parameters.

Comment: Wow! I feel so dumb! Thank you so much for your help :(.